# fetch record from parent child table ......I want to access child table properties from the parent table in parent controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

Parent table
public class Activity
{
public int ActivityId { get; set; }

```
    public string ActivtiyName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<ActivityFeature> ActivityFeature { get; set; }
    
}
```

child table

```
public partial class ActivityFeature
{
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
   
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    //Navigation properties
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

controller
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> GetActivity()
{

```
        //_context.Activity.Include(e => e.ActivityFeature).ToList();
        var Activty = _context.Activity
        .Select(c => new
        {
            ActivityId = c.ActivityId,

            ActivityFeatures = c.ActivityFeature
        }).ToList();


        return _context.Activity;
    }
```

Comment: You showed the classes, thanks. Please show us  the controller you are talking about too.

Comment: Kindly Check it I have Posted get method

Comment: Hi @AbubakarSiddeque, I have tested your code, it could get the child data successfully by using asp.net core 3.1. What is the version of asp.net core? Besides, your return type is `async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>>` it is not correct and even do not be compiled successfully. Maybe you do not know how to return `Activty ` variable?

Comment: I'm using asp.net core 5

Comment: Hi @AbubakarSiddeque, Did you debug the code and check if the `Activty`  variable has data for `ActivityFeatures`? Did you want to get `ActivityFeatures` value from the variable?

Comment: Thanks All. this works for me                                                                                      
 var activty = _context.Activity
.Include(i=> i.ActivityFeature)
.ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 var activty = _context.Activity
.Include(i=> i.ActivityFeature)
.ToList();
```

or if you want for one activity witn id

```
 var activty = _context.Activity
. Where (i=> i.ActivityId==id)
.Include(i=> i.ActivityFeature)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

or just child table

```
 var activtyFeatures = _context.Activity
. Where (i=> i.ActivityId==id)
.Select(i=> i.i.ActivityFeature)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

or the same result

```
var activtyFeatures = _context.ActivityFeature
.Where(i=> i.ActivityId=id)
.ToList();
```